# Jasmine specs are not loading in any of the correct assets using jasmine-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine

I am using the [jasmine-rails gem](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-rails) to try and get our jasmine test suite working.

In my routes right at the top I have defined the following;

```
mount JasmineRails::Engine => '/specs' if defined?(JasmineRails)
```

And that seems to work, I can browse to /specs and the title of the page is *Jasmine Specs*.

The issue is that none of the assets that Jasmine needs are being loaded, including the specs. In my console I am seeing;

```
GET http://acme.lvh.me:8081/specs/assets/jasmine-specs.css 404 (Not Found) specs:21
GET http://acme.lvh.me:8081/specs/assets/jasmine.js 404 (Not Found) specs:22
GET http://acme.lvh.me:8081/specs/assets/jasmine.css 404 (Not Found) specs:20
GET http://acme.lvh.me:8081/specs/assets/jasmine-html.js 404 (Not Found) specs:23
GET http://acme.lvh.me:8081/specs/assets/boot.js 404 (Not Found) specs:25
GET http://acme.lvh.me:8081/specs/assets/json2.js 404 (Not Found) specs:24
GET http://acme.lvh.me:8081/specs/assets/jasmine-specs.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I am not quite sure why /specs/ is in that path?

My jasmine.yml is;

```
spec_files:
  - "**/*[Ss]pec.{js,coffee}"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you indicate what value are you using for "spec_dir" in jasmine.yml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by created a custom template

`app/views/layouts/jasmine_rails/spec_runner.html.erb`

And manually looping and creating the CSS/JS includes;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <title>Jasmine Specs</title>

    <% jasmine_css_files.each do |css_file| %>
      <link href="/assets/<%= css_file %>" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <% end %>

    <% jasmine_js_files.each do |js_file| %>
      <script src="/assets/<%= js_file %>"></script>
    <% end %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="jasmine_content"></div>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```